# Visual Basic Physical Memory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, memory, ram

I'm trying to get the amount of physical memory (Total RAM) installed on my PC through Visual Basic.The problem is that I get as a return "0 bytes".Further I'll also try yo get the percentage of use,the amount of free RAM,Total paging,free page and a graph showing the usage like resource monitor for RAM,in Windows.The problem is that I can't get the correct amount of free RAM first to advance with the others.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

This is my code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
#Region " API "
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Private Structure MEMORYSTATUSEX
        Dim dwLength As Integer
        Dim dwMemoryLoad As Integer
        Dim ullTotalPhys As ULong
    End Structure
    Private memoryInfo As MEMORYSTATUSEX
    Private Declare Auto Sub GlobalMemoryStatusEx Lib "kernel32" (ByRef lpBuffer As MEMORYSTATUSEX)
#End Region


#Region " Variables "

    Private mullTotalRAM As ULong

#End Region

#Region " Form Events "
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' set title
        Me.Text = My.Application.Info.Title & " " & My.Application.Info.Version.Major.ToString & "." & _
            My.Application.Info.Version.Minor.ToString

        Application.DoEvents()
        GetMemoryInfo()
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Information Gathering and Display "

    Private Sub GetMemoryInfo()

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

        ' set size of structure (required by this api call)
        memoryInfo.dwLength = Marshal.SizeOf(memoryInfo)
        GlobalMemoryStatusEx(memoryInfo)

        mullTotalRAM = memoryInfo.ullTotalPhys

        txtRAM.Text = FormatBytes(mullTotalRAM)

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Update Timer "

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        GetMemoryInfo()

        Application.DoEvents()

    End Sub

#End Region


#Region " Formatting Routines "

    Private Function FormatBytes(ByVal ullBytes As ULong) As String
        Dim dblTemp As Double

        Try
            Select Case ullBytes
                Case Is >= 1073741824 'GB
                    dblTemp = CDbl(ullBytes / 1073741824)
                    Return FormatNumber(dblTemp, 2) & " GB"
                Case 1048576 To 1073741823
                    dblTemp = CDbl(ullBytes / 1048576) 'MB
                    Return FormatNumber(dblTemp, 0) & " MB"
                Case 1024 To 1048575
                    dblTemp = CDbl(ullBytes / 1024) 'KB
                    Return FormatNumber(dblTemp, 0) & " KB"
                Case 0 To 1023
                    dblTemp = ullBytes ' bytes
                    Return FormatNumber(dblTemp, 0) & " bytes"
                Case Else
                    Return ""
            End Select
        Catch
            Return ""
        End Try

    End Function


#End Region


    Private Sub ramaTotalRAM_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ramaTotalRAM.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtRAM_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRAM.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

I've resolved this problem.Now I'm wondering if it is possible to make something like this:
http://s18.postimage.org/7zn5adst3/Memory.jpg .How can I do it.thank you very much.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: This ain't VB either, but perhaps VB.Net.

Comment: @Bob Riemersma : I'm using visual studio 2008 and this is a .vb application ("Form1.vb" is the name for it).

Comment: @Eric J. : I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Marketing be damned, VB.Net isn't VB.  By being clear in your tagging you'll get answers quicker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a forums.  If you have two questions, open two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some simple single liners to get the job done:**

***TotalPhysicalMemory***

```
MsgBox(String.Format("TotalPhysicalMemory: {0} MBytes", System.Math.Round(My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory / (1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString)
```

***AvailablePhysicalMemory***

```
    MsgBox(String.Format("AvailablePhysicalMemory: {0} MBytes", System.Math.Round(My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / (1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString)
```

***TotalVirtualMemory***

```
    MsgBox(String.Format("TotalVirtualMemory: {0} MBytes", System.Math.Round(My.Computer.Info.TotalVirtualMemory / (1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString)
```

***AvailableVirtualMemory***

```
    MsgBox(String.Format("AvailableVirtualMemory: {0} MBytes", System.Math.Round(My.Computer.Info.AvailableVirtualMemory / (1024 * 1024)), 2).ToString)
```

or

**Change your API decl to this(notice that `.dll` is missing in you code)**

```
Private Declare Auto Sub GlobalMemoryStatusEx Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef lpBuffer As MEMORYSTATUSEX)
```

Comment: by changing in API declaration "kernel32.dll" it still won't work.The above code,yes,it works,thank you very much.I also tried that one earlier.I still don't understand why my method won't work since in the program that i'm using as a model it works like a charm.I still get 0 bytes from the last case.If i delete that part with Case 0 To 1023 it doesn't return nothing when i run it.The box is empty.I still can't figure it out.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jQS3F7Hh) of working example

I was able to get it working by using this definition of `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` and the below `MEMORYSTATUSEX`

```
Private Declare Auto Sub GlobalMemoryStatusEx Lib "kernel32" (<[In](), Out()> lpBuffer As MEMORYSTATUSEX)
```

and declaring it like

```
 Private memoryInfo As MEMORYSTATUSEX = New MEMORYSTATUSEX
```

and commenting out

```
 'memoryInfo.dwLength = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(memoryInfo))
```

I don't know where you got your structure definition for [`MEMORYSTATUSEX`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MEMORYSTATUSEX.html) but according to Pinvoke.net it is supposed to be.

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Class MEMORYSTATUSEX

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:MEMORYSTATUSEX" /> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
    Me.dwLength = CType(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(MEMORYSTATUSEX)), UInt32)
    End Sub
    ' Fields
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of the structure, in bytes. You must set this member before calling GlobalMemoryStatusEx.
    ''' </summary>
    Public dwLength As UInt32
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Number between 0 and 100 that specifies the approximate percentage of physical memory that is in use (0 indicates no memory use and 100 indicates full memory use).
    ''' </summary>
    Public dwMemoryLoad As UInt32
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Total size of physical memory, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullTotalPhys As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of physical memory available, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullAvailPhys As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of the committed memory limit, in bytes. This is physical memory plus the size of the page file, minus a small overhead.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullTotalPageFile As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of available memory to commit, in bytes. The limit is ullTotalPageFile.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullAvailPageFile As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Total size of the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullTotalVirtual As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the user mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullAvailVirtual As UInt64
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Size of unreserved and uncommitted memory in the extended portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ullAvailExtendedVirtual As UInt64
End Class
```

You can also look at the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.aspx) Class

```
Dim info As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo 
Debug.Print(CStr(info.TotalPhysicalMemory))
Debug.Print(CStr(info.TotalVirtualMemory))
Debug.Print(CStr(info.AvailablePhysicalMemory))
```

Comment: I have a similar application and it is used MEMORYSTATUSEX and it works,it shows me the right amount of RAM but in my case it won't work .

Comment: I just finished the part showing the Free RAM and still "0 bytes" as a result.In the similar application I have found on the web it shows me the right amount.Is is something about the dialog box that shows the output.It is set as read only:true,accept returns:true,and modifiers:public.

Comment: @TeoRoxy added some additional information. I was not able to get your code to work using your structure, I used the one that I posted and even then I had to change the GlobalMemoryStatusEX declaration. So the above does work, I am not sure why yours is not working.

Comment: Thank you very much.I've noticed that if i delete the part with Case 0 To 1023 my application won't return anything when I run it.If I leave it,I get "0 bytes".I thing something is wrong there,but I can't figure out what.The application that i'm using as a model still works like a charm with the same code.Thank you again.

Comment: @TeoRoxy is my example working for you? Because I am getting a Result of 7.88GB on my Computer? Put a breakpoint on your Case Statement to find out what ullBytes is.

Comment: i've done the modifications and it works.I'm very grateful.Thank you very much.Can I get a contact e-mail address in case a I need more help?I'm kind of beginner in vb.If not,I'll still ask here.Next step i want to make a simple progress bar showing the RAM usage.

Comment: @TeoRoxy you can always add a comment to this question and I will see it. But if it is a new question it would be best to ask a new one, there are a lot of very good programmers on SO. Just remember that when someone does answer your question to mark the answer as accepted, that will close the question and give you and them some additional rep.

Comment: I've finished my application.How can i export it to work outside visual studio?I want to run it outside the programming interface.Thank you.

Comment: @TeoRoxy Is it going to be run on your machine only, or do you plan on moving it to another machine. If your machine only your executable file is in your projectdirectory\Bin\Debug or Release depending on your build options. otherwise use visual studio setup Wizard under other projects

Comment: Hello again!Do you know if it is possible to make something like this in VB: http://s18.postimage.org/7zn5adst3/Memory.jpg  .Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
Friend Sub ReleaseMemory()
        Try
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            If Environment.OSVersion.Platform = PlatformID.Win32NT Then
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogError(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```